# How should a Dockerfile look like to run the default rails 6 project with yarn?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

After a year hiatus I tried to run the default rails 6 project with docker/docker-compose.

At first I had bundler issues. But it was solved with `ENV BUNDLER_VERSION 2.0.1`

Now I got an issue with yarn. Could you look at the following configs and tell me what I'm doing wrong. Thank you!

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ruby:2.6.3

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y nodejs yarn postgresql-client

RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

ENV BUNDLER_VERSION 2.0.1

RUN gem install bundler && bundle install --jobs 20 --retry 5
RUN yarn install

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["bundle", "exec", "rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
FROM ruby:2.6.3
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Here's the output of `docker-compose build`
After it installs the gems, I can see the following output:

```
Removing intermediate container b74374c81e66
 ---> bbb8e3ba24d1
Step 8/10 : RUN yarn install
 ---> Running in 3343917857c7
Parsing scenario file install
ERROR: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'install'
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c yarn install' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

**EDIT**

If I use the following Dockerfile, it works. But I don't think this is best solution.

```
FROM ruby:2.6.3

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y npm nodejs yarn postgresql-client

RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json /app
RUN npm i -g yarn && yarn

COPY . /app

ENV BUNDLER_VERSION 2.0.1

RUN gem install bundler && bundle install --jobs 20 --retry 5
RUN yarn install

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["bundle", "exec", "rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

Comment: example here can help you https://shivab.com/blog/docker/2019/01/15/dockerization-of-rails-6-app/

Answer (score 2):

My first few lines of Dockerfile are as follows:

```
FROM ruby:2.5.1

# Ensure we install an up-to-date version of Node
# See https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/2888
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash -

# Ensure latest packages for Yarn
RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list

# Allow apt to work with https-based sources
RUN apt-get update -yqq && apt-get install -yqq --no-install-recommends \
    apt-transport-https \
    nodejs \
    postgresql-client \
    yarn
```

Comment: Interesting. This worked with just `RUN yarn install`

Comment: Actually. It breaks `docker-compose up ` . Here's the error: ```warning Integrity check: System parameters don't match
web_1  | error Integrity check failed
web_1  | error Found 1 errors.```. ```Your Yarn packages are out of date!
web_1  |   Please run `yarn install --check-files` to update.```

Comment: Did you try running `yarn install --check-files`?

Comment: Yes. I mean it builds fine. The problem is with that Integrity check. I tried disabling it in config/webpacker.yml but it throwed another error `Exiting
web_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/rb-inotify-0.10.0/lib/rb-inotify/notifier.rb:194:in initialize: Not a directory @ dir_initialize - /app/app/package.json (Errno::ENOTDIR)`

Answer (score 1):

sometimes if `cmdtest` is installed on the host when using apt to install yarn may cause the obove Problem try to do the following:

```
RUN apt-get remove -y cmdtest && apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y nodejs postgresql-client
```

then install yrn using the script:

```
curl -o- -L https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | bash
```

when that still does not work see this [commit](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/3708#issuecomment-317358958)

Comment: Even after the manipulations that you shared I had `No such file or directory: 'install'` when executing `RUN yarn install` 

But then I found I could use `RUN $HOME/.yarn/bin/yarn` and it worked perfectly fine. I still don't understand why it's so problematic to perform such a simple task and the default docs don't cover this info. (https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/)